# Something caused this CSS to break

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static site based off a theme. The CSS has not been touched but something caused it to break recently. I was a bit confused since I hadn't made any changes so I checked the example site and it's broken there as well. I checked with the author, no new changes but they also noticed it's broken for them now.

So the issue. On Safari, IE, Chrome, and Edge there is a weird header weird "pop-in(?)" upon page load. All elements are shifted down immediately. Firefox operates properly.

It's easiest to see on this page https://mmistakes.github.io/so-simple-theme/theme-setup/, but effects all pages in the theme.

I'm not a CSS wizard but after troubleshooting for a day I found it may be related to this CSS selector? I could be completely wrong.

```
#site-nav {
    display: none;
    z-index: 5
}
```

Second question (less important) is I'm wondering what could cause something to break after the fact. I'm assuming one of the JavaScript libraries linked in?

Thanks much!

Comment: I just looked at this site in Chrome and Firefox and they both looked fine.  Could you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an annotated screenshot of the issue at hand? It may not be immediately clear to everyone what you mean by "pop-in".

Comment: If the author also is affected they will find that quickly and fix it.

Comment: A third party JS library was most likely the culprit. You don't have control over their updates. My guess since I don't see it would be it is coming from the ad service at the bottom of your page. Try removing it and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @user1661890 Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the reason your content, say "pops-in" or simply shifts down abruptly is because the content just appears when page is loaded.

To fix this initialize your CSS to start like:

```css
#site-nav {
  height: 0;
  transition: height .2s, max-height 200ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then in your `@media` for `48em` have your css do this:

```css
#site-nav.closed {
  height: 5em;
}
```

This will ensure your content actually slides in and no abrupt behavior exists anywhere.